# How to query multiple result in specify value in dapper

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I want return all records when data.Task = 0 in this query. how to do it?

```
var data = SqlConn.ConnectSQL().Query("Select TicketNo, PickName From TaxiTicket Where DriverID = @ID AND Status = @State",
                        new { ID = find.Account, State = data.Task });
```

Comment: It is return all records.  Add a .ToList() to end of statement so you see the results.

Comment: Are you sure that this code compiles? How do you manage to declare a variable _data_ when you have already a _data_ used in the parameter list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var data = SqlConn.ConnectSQL().Query("Select TicketNo, PickName From TaxiTicket 
Where DriverID = @ID AND (Status = case @State when 0 then Status else @state end)",
                        new { ID = find.Account, State = data.Task });`

this only addresses your point of question, how you prepare and pass parameters is another issue. you seem to have some weird assignment using same `data` variable.